Generalization of formally real fields to fields equipped with an involution
Let $K$ be a field. If $0$ cannot be written as a sum of nonzero squares in $K$, then $K$ is a formally real field.
Now, if $K$ is a field with involution $*$, do we have a name for fields in which $0$ cannot be written as a sum of nonzero $aa^*$? That is $$0 = \sum_i a_ia_i^* \Rightarrow a_i=0 \text{ for all } i.$$
Added Later:
Involution is an antihomomorphism of order 1 or 2:
$$1^* = 1$$
$$(a^*)^*=a$$
$$(a+b)^*=a^*+b^*$$
$$(ab)^*=b^*a^*.$$
Is it true to say the fixed field $F$ of involution should be formally real? and $K=F$ if $*$ is trivial, otherwise $K/F$ is a quadratic extension of $F$?

I added the missing axiom $1^=1$. Maybe you want to add the axiom $a a^ = 0 \implies a=0$ as well (even though it's $n=1$ in your condition).

Why that would be useful? I also think $1^*=1$ is redundant.

It can be derived from the other properties since you are working in a field / integral domain. The general notion of an involution includes $1^*=1$. In any case, a good definition should be "scalable", not "minimal".

About the other one, we are using $a^2 =0 \implies a=0$ all the time. So the same should happen here as well - that was my idea. Compare this also with the notion of a C$^$-algebra. You also spoke of "zero squares", which would translate to $a a^ =0$, but you already wrote $a=0$ (plus indices).

The fixed field $F$ of the involution is formally real. Indeed, let $n$ be a natural number and $a_1,\dots, a_n$ be any elements of $F$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2=0$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ia_i^*=0$, so $a_i=0$ for each natural $i\le n$.
Since $F$ is formally real, its characteristics is the infinity, so for any $a\in K$ we can put $\bar a=a-\frac{a+a^*}2$. Then $a\in F(\bar a)$ and $\bar a^*=-\bar a$, so $\bar a^2=-\bar a\bar a^*\in F$, that is $\bar a$ is a root of the equation $x^2+\bar a\bar a^*=0$.
Now suppose that $*$ is not trivial, so there exists an element $a$ of $K$ such that $a^*\ne a$ and thus $\bar a\ne 0$. For any element $b\in K$ we have $(\bar b\bar a)^*=\bar b\bar a$, so $\bar b\bar a\in F$, thus $b\in F(\bar b)\subset F(\bar a)$.


do we have a name for such fields?

No, I don't believe so. The obvious name would seem to be "formally complex field," which doesn't seem to have ever been used. I've found no references to this notion, nobody's come along with such a name so far, and the sources I looked at didn't mention it. Perhaps it's hiding somewhere under a name that didn't catch on or some symbols in a paper, because it's a fairly natural variation on a standard topic.
